# How do I add spacing within an ul li

Tags: css, html-lists, spacing

Please see the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Jk6Bk/5/)

I would like to add some spacing between 'Leonard' and the 'X' (delete button).

I tried `margin-left` in the css for `ul li a` element, but that does not seem to work.

I'm missing something stupid here, any idea what it is?

Comment: Set a width on the li element maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector `ul li a` to `ul li a.button`
The `.button` selector is more specific than  `ul li a` and its margin is overriding.

from [html Dog: Specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) we can give the classes the following weights:

1. `.button` weight: 10
2. `ul li a` weight: 3
3. `ul li a.button` weight: 13

So by specifying a class myou can override the default `margin` on the `.button` class

Comment: @Arun Yeah its a different solution pointing out the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add `margin-left` to the `.button` class itself:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin-left: 50px;
    ...
}
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jk6Bk/13/).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

```
<li>Leonard &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type='image' src='x.png'></li>
```

Comment: While this would work, usually changing the html is worse than finding a css solution.

Comment: Adding nbsp is not a solution it's a workaround which is not needed in 99% of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add display:block; in your ul li a CSS then only the margin right will be work

```
ul li a{
    float:right;
    display:block;

    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/Jk6Bk/10/

```
<li class="ui-state-default cloneable"><label style="float:left; width:100px;">Bob</label><span class="ss"><a href="#" class="button small bigrounded red" onclick="removePersonFromList(this);return false;">X</a></span></li>


                <li class="ui-state-default cloneable"><label style="float:left; width:100px;">Leonard</label><span><a href="#" class="button small bigrounded red" onclick="removePersonFromList(this);return false;">X</a></span></li>


                    <li class="ui-state-default cloneable"><label style="float:left; width:100px;">Boris</label><span><a href="#" class="button small bigrounded red" onclick="removePersonFromList(this);return false;">X</a></span></li>
```

above i have edited

```
<label style="float:left; width:100px">your content</label><span>your content</span>
```

For every li i have used it. i hope you understand. thanks

Comment: Some explanation or the specific code/markup you changed woiuld be helpful to the OP.

Comment: i have add the label tag and apply style float:left and width:100px for separation.

Comment: Adding style for every element is not a solution when you have css.

Answer (score 0):

The margin on .button is overriding the margin on the a. Just remove the margin rule from .button.